# Check if an string has an integer in an if condition

Tags: python

```
file = open('Name.txt', 'r')
name =  str(file.read())
file.close()
```

In the file called 'Name.txt', the user will input a name. The program is to check whether or not the name is valid.

E.g:

1bob - is not valid

bob - is valid

Is it possible to do this with an if condition?

Comment: The requirements for your validation are not clearly stated. And how have you attempted to solve this? The code you posted is almost not related to the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use regular expression :

i.e :

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'.*[0-9]')
>>> names = ['Bob', 'John', '1Bob', 'John2']
>>> for name in names: 
...     if not regex.match(name):
...          print name
... 
Bob
John
```

`.*` matches any character (except newline)

Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times

`[0-9]` match a single character present in the list below

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Please, if somebody down votes, please tell my why. If my answer is not good, I'd like to know why. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
def validate(my_file):
    return not any(x.isdigit() for x in open(my_file).read().strip())
```

The above function will return True when name is valid else False.